# setInterval issue with multiple ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax

I have been reading about setInterval and came up with my own way to send multiple ajax requests from one page. The problem is that once i press button 2 after pressing button 1, it stops sending multiple requests and if i press button 1 again it does not stop previous setInterval() and starts parallel requests. What i am trying to achieve is that when i press button 1 it must only print "1" 30 times and when i press button 2, it must stop printing "1" but print "2" after sleeping for 5 seconds and if i press button 1 again it must again start printing "1" and stop printing "2". Following is my code:

```
<script language='javascript'>
var request = 0;
var request1 = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hi button").click(function () {

        var id = this.id;
        if(request!=0){
            clearInterval(request);
            request1.abort();
        }
        request = setInterval(do_it,1000,id);           
    });
});

function do_it(id) {
        request1 = $.ajax({ 
        url: "php.php?id=" + id,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
            }
        });
}
</script>

<div class="hi" id="hi">
    <button id="1" ></button>
    <button id="2" ></button>
    </div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$word='';
include('sql_connect.php');
if($_GET['id'] == '1') {
    $main = '1';

    for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
        $word .= $main . "<br>";
    }
    echo $word;
}

if($_GET['id'] == '2') {
    $a = 0; 

    while($a != 1) {
        sleep(5);
        $a=1;
    }               
    echo "2";
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Don't you want `request1.abort()`?

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what I have in my original script. still same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting a function in setInterval, the function should be encased in quotes or you can use an anonymous function (example below is encased in quotes).
Also, you're specifying an incorrect third parameter for setInterval.

The third parameter in setInterval is:
Lang: Optional parameter to specify the scripting language e.g.: Jscript, Javascript, vbscript.

```
setInterval(do_it, 1000, id);
```

Should be

```
setInterval('do_it(' + id + ')', 1000);
```

Comment: also, you would probably want to do the 5 second delay on the client side. as written, your server code pauses 5 seconds for every ajax call with id=2 it receives, and since your javascript keeps sending many ajax messages with id=2, this will get backed up real fast. $a does not retain its value on subsequent requests sent to the php script, or whatever it was that you were thinking here.

Comment: I tried that and now it does not print anything. When i do alert(id); (after "function do_it(id) {
") it says [object HTML Button Element]. So that means it is not passing the parameters properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the setTimeout in the following way

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        do_it(id);
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with jquery (I just use javascript out of the box), but I have dealt with making ajax calls in timed loops in the past.  One thing to consider is that if you are making asynchronous ajax calls, then the setInterval/setTimeout will continue to run regardless if the previous ajax responses have been called (unless if you call setTimeout in the response function, then the ajax request and response calls will run synchronously).  Or you can just do syncronous ajax calls -- if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the output of `clearInterval()` to `request` so it doesnt hit the `if` statement again: `request = clearInterval(request);` - this will cause `request` to equal `undefined`, therefore i wouldn't assign your variables at the top, do:

```
var request;
var request1;

...

if(request) {...}
```

Also im fairly sure the 3rd param for `setInterval()` is not the arguements you wish to pass to the function you defined - you would do that like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    do_it(id);
}, 1000);
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: The `(callback, delay[, additional-params])` is a valid syntax option for `setInterval`, but it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: The value of `request` is already reassigned right outside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at above answers helped me find a good solution. This is what i did:

```
request1 = $.ajax({ 

url: "php.php?id=" + id,
success: function (result) {
    $("#result").html(result);
    do_it(id); 
} });


function do_it(id) {
        //alert(id);
        request1 = $.ajax({ 
        url: "php.php?id=" + id,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
            request = setTimeout(do_it,1000,id);
            }
        });
}
```

Although I could still not pass the parameter properly using setTimeout('do_it(' + id + ')', 1000); , it worked for me.